# DocPad: Filter Posts By Date

Tags: docpad

My YAML looks like this...

```
---
title: "Sample 003"
layout: "post"
isPage: true
date: 2014-06-21
---
```

In docpad.coffee, I have the following (which is there by default)...

```
collections:
    posts: ->
        @getCollection("html").findAllLive({relativeOutDirPath: 'posts'},[{date:-1}])
```

This works well, in the sense that it returns all posts and does so in descending order.

However, I would like to add multiple posts "in advance".  As such, I would like to date them with dates that occur in the future.  What I need to know how to do is modify the posts collection such that it only returns posts that are dated "today" or before.

As always, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like:

`collections:
    posts: ->
        @getCollection("html").findAllLive({relativeOutDirPath: 'posts', date: $lt new Date()},[{date:-1}])`